# Check continuously if a file exists with PHP

Tags: php, file, exists

I am working on a project that requires me to check for the existence of a file with PHP every 5 seconds, and if the file exists, redirect to it.

If it doesn't exist, the script should keep checking every 5 seconds instead.

How would I go about doing that? I know about file_exists(), but how would I go about making it check continuously, not just once?

Comment: write a infinite while loop and call `sleep(5)` before `file_exists()` inside loop. In this way you can check (after every 5 second) if file exist or not.

Comment: You need javascript and ajax for that also.

Comment: I'm curious as to what happens to make the file suddenly exist? But moreso, the answer to this (as per @ChukwuemekaIhedoro's answer) will cause it to check infinitely unless a file is ever found.

Comment: @James Not only that, how do you know the *entire* file exists?  The people who come up with these kinds of designs that misuse a filesystem as a communication channel almost never seem to think of that.

Answer (score 3):

you can try using this

```
<?php
$x = 0;
$count = 5;

do {
    if(!file_exists($file)){
        $x++;
        echo 'file loading';
        sleep(5);//Delays the program execution for 5seconds before code continues. 
    }
    else {
        header('Location: '.$file);
        exit();
    }
}
while($x < $count); // this kind of regulates how long the loop should last to avoid maximum execution timeout error

if($x == $count){
    echo 'file does not exist';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you - I forgot to add that there will also be a HTML page served to the visitor along with the PHP code, that will inform them that their request is being processed. Once the file becomes available, it is then that the redirection should occur. Also, isn't the above function gonna cause php maximum execution time to expire?